# android demo can，t response to boot event

Tags: android, broadcast

I write a demo to test receive boot broadcast.The application contains two classes(MainActivity.java & BootCompleteReceiver.java).Codes are listed in follow:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

BootCompleteReceiver.java:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

the demo runs well in nexus 4,but in meizu note2 it dosen't show toast,it puzzles me a lot.